# How do I implement Dual-encoder model in Pytorch?

Tags: transformer, encoder

I am trying to implement the paper titled Learning Cross-lingual Sentence Representations via a Multi-task Dual-Encoder Model.

Here the encoder and decoder share the same weights but I am unable to put it in code. Any links ?

Answer (score 0):

There isnt any as of yet, but scout this [website](https://paperswithcode.com/search?q_meta=&q=Learning%20Cross-lingual%20Sentence%20Representations%20via%20a%20Multi-task%20Dual-Encoder%20Model) and as soon as it comes it will be there.

Comment: Bad luck... Will try to find a code-base which performs multi-tasking in the similar fashion. Thanks